# How to pass the onorientationchange() event to iframe sites?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

How can I pass the `onorientationchange()` event to iframe-based sites?

Comment: Apple Comment: this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 7423082.

Comment: you could use cross document messages to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798063/detect-orientation-change-from-within-cross-domain-iframe/7668806#7668806

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (self != top) {
      window.top.location = window.self.location;
    }
    window.onorientationchange = function () {
        switch (window.orientation) {
            case 0:
                alert('PORTRAIT');
                break;
            case 90:
                alert('LANDSCAPE');
                break;
            case -90:
                alert('LANDSCAPE');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```