# Detect orientation change in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a Html page, inside that page there is a iframe. In the Iframe src page I have written code to detect orientation and do some things.
The orientation change is detected when I launch the iframe URL separately in browser, but when I use iframe, the orientation change is not detected. Do I need to use any plug in for this?

Comment: Are you talking about mobile device orientation?

Comment: yes, Mobile or tablet screen

Comment: You could detect the orientationchange on parent document and then provide the info on callback to the iframe, e.g. using postMessage API. How about that?

Comment: You might want to add that information to the title and description of your problem. The solution might device-dependent - unfortunately, I don't know it.

Comment: I don't have control on parent document, It is clients page

Comment: So your client is able to add the iframe on his page but he's unwilling to add few lines of code to make everything work? Well, that sounds bad. There's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798063/detect-orientation-change-from-within-cross-domain-iframe

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works, Now just need to convince the client :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work only if your iframe is on the same domain, and if they fire 'orientationchange' event.

```
$(document).add(parent.document).on('orientationchange',function() {
 // your logic
});
```